# Is a random walk in 1.585-dimensional space transient or recurrent?

Tags: markov-process, random-walk, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

A drunk man will eventually find his way home, but a drunk bird may get lost forever.

Will a drunk squirrel eventually climb down the 3-branch tree?

[image]

Comment: What are the actual nodes that the squirrel is climbing on? Is it the branches in the center, or the leaves on the outside? Because if it's the branches in the center, this is basically a random walk on a Bethe lattice, which is transient unless the lattice degenerates to a line. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe_lattice

Comment: Indeed, we go from the integer lattice to Bethe lattice. What really captivates me is the question why this simple "man-bird" criteria does or doesn't apply to Hausdorff dimensions.

Comment: What would be the answer for a random walk on a modified (by changing the angles) Koch curve with the same fractal dimension?

Comment: In my view, Koch curve is equivalent to the integer grid after a finite number of iterations but I'm unsure if a random walk can be defined on the approached limit

Comment: Your question is very poetic, but it fails to meet the standards of this site.  Can you please reformulate the question into an actual mathematical question (in some place other than the title)?  Can you please edit your question to include relevant definitions (e.g. *which* 1.585 dimensional space?  how is it constructed?  how is the random walk defined on that space?  what are your definitions of "transient" and "recurrent"? etc)?